# Did I do something wrong with this formula

Tags: java

I was wondering if I messed up somewhere in my code. I tested it using 5.5 for the radius and 12 for height. My professor had different results. Hers came up as 1140.40 and mine came up as 1139.82. I'm currently using eclipse and I've been told to use java.lang.Math.pow as that is the exponent method.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AreaVolumeOfACylinder {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Data Types
    double r = 0.0;
    double h = 0.0;
    double V = 0.0;
    double pi = 3.14;
    // Inputs
    System.out.println("Enter the radius of the cylinder: ");
    r = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the height of the cylinder: ");
    h = input.nextDouble();
    // Formula Processing
    r = java.lang.Math.pow(r, 2);
    V = pi * r * h;
    //Outputs
    System.out.printf("The volume is %.2f%n", V);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you change the title to describe the objective of the formula? It is assumed since you are posting here that you have a possible coding error.  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try using double pi = 3.141592;

Comment: I edited you question because it looked like you seemed to have replaced it with some garbage text.  If you don't want the question to be seen anymore, just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your `double pi = 3.14` is not accurate enough. Try using Math.PI instead.

Comment: For something that simple a comment would have sufficed.